# Cycle through query windows SSMS 2008 RC

Tags: ssms

Does anyone know how to cycle through the open query windows in SSMS?

Seems simple but cannot find a way to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard windows shortcut: CTRL+Tab